# C# regEx expression not matching newline

Tags: c#, regex

This is my file test1.txt

```
Line 4:   http://go34.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=333333
    Line 4:   http://go/p.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=333333
```

I want to write a regex expression that match's the 2 URLs listed here. Here is the regEx expression I am using

```
string pattern = "http://go.*?.microsoft.com/fwlink.*?[\r\n]";
```

I am expecting the match to be as follows :

```
http://go34.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=333333
http://go/p.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=333333
```

I am just not able to get the match's and cant figure out why its not matching. The same regex expression works in notepad++. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help.

Comment: probably not matching because the second line doesn't have a newline at the end

Comment: You want two URLs in one match, or do you want to return multiple matches? I feel like this should be evident, but I am having my doubts. Perhaps make your `[\r\n]` optional with `?`

Answer (score 4):

```
string pattern = "http://go.*?.microsoft.com/fwlink.*?$";

var urls = Regex.Matches(text, pattern,RegexOptions.Multiline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => m.Value.Trim())
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\s*http://go\S*\.microsoft.com/fwlink\S*\s*", RegexOptions.Multiline)`. This will match any line that contains only your url surrounded by any number of white space characters.

`Regex.Repalce(input, @"\s*(http://go.*\.microsoft.com/fwlink\S*)\s*", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline)` will get only the matched url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//note the @ at the beginning
string pattern = @"http://go.*?.microsoft.com/fwlink.*?[\r\n]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a blank line (hit Enter) at the end of your file?  Does your file actually end in \r\n?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your string is just ending with **Line Feed** aka *"\n"* instead of the **Carriage Return Line Feed** aka *"\r\n"*, maybe you can try this `\r?\n` at the end of your regular expression.

Also, you can use `$` metacharacter in conjunction with `[^]` in order to match anything except new line, Example:

```
string pattern = "http://go.*?.microsoft.com/fwlink[^$+]"
```